# Ontologies in .NET

Tags: c#, owl, ontology

I need to make use of some OWL ontologies in c#. Does anyone have a suggestion where I can start? Or if there are any libraries available for .NET please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at [ROWLEX](http://rowlex.nc3a.nato.int/):

> ROWLEX is a powerful open source toolkit for software developers. It has been built to simplify the use of fundamental semantic web technologies (RDF and OWL) under Microsoft’s .NET platform.

Comment: Does it let you add an OWL which is already created, or you have to create it manually in the .NET app?

Comment: I think you have to generate an assembly for it, but there's a tool for this (see OwlGrinder) near the bottom of http://rowlex.nc3a.nato.int/HowToUse.aspx

Comment: thanks ! this looks really good. what i dont understand is when we load the OWL, do we load a schema or the whole thing with all the entities we need and information?

Comment: Not sure since I haven't used that piece.  you might want to ask a new question with the rowlex/owl tags -- I think the ROWLEX dev answers questions around here from time to time:  http://stackoverflow.com/users/112091/rowlex-admin

Answer (score 2):

Use Protege this is a open source tool of ontology editor and a knowledge acquisition system. It gives a GUI to define ontologies.

Comment: yeah... protege is really helpfull

Answer (score 0):

You can use [RDFSharp](http://rdfsharp.codeplex.com/) on Microsoft Codeplex. It has a semantic extension capable of modeling, validating and reasoning on OWL-DL ontologies.